# gradle is not building and project is also not opening in android View

Tags: android, android-studio

i had cloned the project from the Github but the file is not working even the project is not opening in the Android View and i gradle files are not building. is there anyone who can help me resolving this issue? [Here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/shjSM.png)
 of errors

Comment: your internet is working?

Comment: yes my internet is perfectly working. btw thanks for your answer, the error is resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you have enabled the offline mode of gradle sync in android studio.
you can toggle from here as in attached screenshot.
[image]

After that just sync the project and make sure your internet is working fine.
Happy Coding!

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: If this answer was helpful , either accept it as answer or upvote it.
Thanks!